# PuTTY Cygwin nano screen error

Tags: ssh, cygwin, putty, nano

I have recently installed Cygwin on my Windows 7 x64 computer so I can use nano to edit files from the command line. I have also setup OpenSSH to be able to connect to it remotely using PuTTY from my work computer.

My problem is that if I try using nano with line numbering the screen in PuTTY terminal doesn't seem to update correctly as shown in the image.

```
nano -c test.txt
```

[image: screenshot]

If I use nano from Windows CMD console or using OpenSSH client it works correctly, so the problem seems to be with the PuTTY terminal.

Another problem I'm facing is that the `clear` command doesn't work properly when using SSH, so I had to use `set TERM=cygwin` to "fix" this but even then the command only skips a line and doesn't scroll the screen. I have also tried using MobaXterm but with the same results as with PuTTY.

Is there any configuration I can set to get this working properly?

Comment: Is your login shell bash?  (common for cygwin).  Does running `export TERM=vt100` improve the behavior at all?

Comment: @BowlOfRed If by login shell you mean the shell I use to SSH into my home computer then it is PuTTY's shell. Both computers are running Win7 x64. As for using `TERM=vt100` it has the same result, perhaps even worse.

Comment: The shell is started by the cygwin SSHD, not the putty side.  You can try `echo $SHELL`

Comment: I don't use cygwin SSHD, I use OpenSSH (not sure if there is a difference or not). Running the command outputs `/bin/bash`

Comment: The reason I asked is that `set TERM=cygwin` isn't appropriate for bash.  You were probably wanting something like `export TERM=cygwin`.  If you do `echo $TERM`, is it set to what you've intended?

Comment: If I do `echo $TERM` it is set to what I have intended in bash. And even using `export TERM=vt100` it gives the exact result as before. Quick note: using `echo $TERM` directly in Windows CMD just outputs $TERM, so I have to execute bash and then use the command in order to get the TERM variable output. Also, `echo %TERM%` outputs the intdended TERM in Windows CMD.